# Web application UI look like eclipse UI

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, angular6

I am trying to design UI in angular 6 that application intention is to provide complete eclipse interface and its functionality.
any plugins to integrate eclipse in web application(angular) to get all the functionalities and buttons etc or any suggestions?

FYI https://help.eclipse.org I have seen only this site look like eclipse UI.

Comment: See [Eclipse RAP](https://www.eclipse.org/rap), in particular the [RAP Workbench Demo](http://rap.eclipsesource.com/demo/release/workbench/).

Comment: Thank you so much @howlger I will look into it.